# pytest failing on warnings, but only on circleci

Tags: python-3.x, pytest, circleci

I have a python project that I'm using circleci to do automatic tests on...

The last line in my circelci.yml is:

```
            python -m pytest tests/ -vv -rsx
```

When I run this command on my computer, the tests all pass.

When I run it on circelci, I get:

```
E   DeprecationWarning: the imp module is deprecated in favour of importlib; see the module's documentation for alternative uses
```

I understand I should fix this eventually, but a warning shouldn't be causing pytest to fail, unless I ask it to with -W... is circleci automatically throwing on a -W?  or is something else going on?

Comment: perhaps it treats warnings as errors within circleci. you can ignore this warning by adding it to your `pytest.ini` file so it isn't thrown rather than using the `-W` flag

Comment: How do you turn off a -W flag that's been turned on elsewhere?

Comment: I am not sure I follow, what do you mean?

Comment: I guess I don't understand your suggestion.

Comment: https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/warnings.html if you look where it talks about the `pytest.ini` file you should see how you can suppress these warnings without the need for flags

Comment: Can you share the link to an example job log?

Comment: I fixed the problem by making the warning go away... it was easier than whatever this was...